# awk not working in bash -c "somecommand | awk '{print $2}'"

Tags: bash, awk, subshell

This command works as expected:

```
(dpkg -l | egrep "linux.+3.8.0.*44" | awk '{print $2}')
linux-generic-lts-raring
linux-headers-3.8.0-44
linux-headers-3.8.0-44-generic
linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic
linux-image-generic-lts-raring
```

However, when I run it with `bash -c` it doesn't work:

```
bash -c "(dpkg -l | egrep "linux.+3.8.0.*44" | awk '{print $2}')"
ii  linux-generic-lts-raring         3.8.0.44.44                       Generic     Linux kernel image and headers
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-44           3.8.0-44.66~precise1              Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.8.0
ii  linux-headers-3.8.0-44-generic   3.8.0-44.66~precise1              Linux kernel headers for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic-lts-raring 3.8.0.44.44                       Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic     3.8.0-44.66~precise1              Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-raring   3.8.0.44.44                       Generic Linux kernel image
```

I have no clue why. It's almost as if the pipe is breaking.

Comment: Could you generate an example that people who aren't on Debian-derived distros can copy/paste/run?

Comment: That said, one very obvious problem is the quotes passed to `egrep` being of the same type used on the outside.

Comment: ...why use both grep and awk as separate commands, anyhow? `bash -c "dpkg -l | awk '/linux.+3[.]8[.]0.*44/ {  print $2 }'"`. Oh. Except the ` $2` doesn't work there.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, ...indeed, but unless the OP has some unusual filenames in their current working directory, `linux.+3.8.0.*44` looks to me like it's not likely to be expanding incorrectly unquoted (as they're inadvertently doing). Unless, of course, `IFS` is at a non-default value that contains any characters present in the string.

Comment: I don't have a non-Debian box at my disposal.

Comment: Changing the double-quotes to single-quotes doesn't fix the issue

Comment: You could replace `dpkg -l` with `printf '%s\n' "foo bar baz"`, and that would suffice to make a non-Debian-specific example.

Comment: Of course it doesn't, because then you have other problems with your *embedded* single quotes. That doesn't mean the outer double quotes aren't the problem; it just means changing them to single quotes without any other alterations isn't the solution.

Comment: The suggested command, `bash -c "dpkg -l | awk '/linux.+3[.]8[.]0.*44/ { print $2 }'"` doesn't work as I want - I still get all the columns, not just the second one

Comment: ...you see the edit above, with the "Oh. Except the `$2` doesn't work there`, in my comment? That edit is saying that I know that the above code won't work, and why it didn't work, making an amendment telling me that it doesn't work... rather redundant.

Comment: ...so, let me explain the "why" one more time: In `bash -c "(dpkg -l | egrep "linux.+3.8.0.*44" | awk '{print $2}')"`, the invoking shell (not the bash you're starting, but the one that read your `bash -c` command) expands the `$2`, making the command it runs `bash -c "(dpkg -l | egrep "linux.+3.8.0.*44" | awk '{print }')"`, which prints the whole line of input, not only `$2`.

Comment: ...there are other bugs, like `3.8.0` not escaping the `.`s you mean to be literal and thus being willing to match, say, `348-0` just as much as `3.8.0`, and the double-quotes you're passing to `grep` closing the double quotes that started your `grep -c` command so that the string you're grepping for is expanded unquoted, but those aren't the immediate problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're in double quotes, `$2` gets expanded by the shell, not passed literally to `awk`. And `print` in awk, by default, prints `$0`, ie. the entire line of input, so if it's expanded to an empty value, there's your problem.

```
bash -c "(dpkg -l | egrep 'linux.+3.8.0.*44' | awk '{print \$2}')"
```

By the way -- there's no point to using `grep` and `awk` separately.

```
bash -c "dpkg -l | awk '/linux.+3.8.0.*44/ { print \$2 }'"
```

If your enclosing shell is itself bash, then one can use `$''` as an alternate means to provide literal strings:

```
# $'' only works with bash, ksh, etc., but won't interpret $2, and lets
# you pass literal quotes
bash -c $'dpkg -l | awk \'/linux.+3[.]8[.]0.*44/ { print $2 }\''
```

By contrast, if your enclosing shell is baseline POSIX, including literal single-quotes inside a single-quoted string gets a bit more complicated.

```
bash -c 'dpkg -l | awk '"'"'/linux.+3[.]8[.]0.*44/ { print $2 }'"'"''
```